# Websphere MQ message purged (destructive read) instead of browsed

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I am trying to Browse a message on a queue. For some reason the message is purged/removed (destructive read) instead of being browsed.

This are my OpenOptions:

```
int openOptions2 = CMQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF
                 | CMQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING
                 | CMQC.MQOO_INQUIRE
                 | CMQC.MQOO_BROWSE;
```

And this is my GetOptions:

```
qMQGetMessageOptions.options = CMQC.MQGMO_NO_WAIT | CMQC.MQGMO_BROWSE_FIRST;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
int openOptions2 = CMQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING | CMQC.MQOO_INQUIRE | CMQC.MQOO_BROWSE;
```

And:

```
MQMessage getMsg;
qMQGetMessageOptions.options = CMQC.MQGMO_NO_WAIT | CMQC.MQGMO_BROWSE_FIRST;

while (true)
{
   getMsg = new MQMessage();
   inQ.get(getMsg, qMQGetMessageOptions);
   qMQGetMessageOptions.options = CMQC.MQGMO_NO_WAIT | CMQC.MQGMO_BROWSE_NEXT;
}
```

Comment: Roger, thanks for the piece of code. I was stupid: Never added the getMessageOptions to my get statment. I had `inQ.get(getMsg);` instead of `inQ.get(getMsg, qMQGetMessageOptions);`